# 'Object not found' error when loading party package in R

Tags: r, package, party

I'm trying to load the party package in R.  I have all the relevant dependencies installed, but when I type `library(party)`, I get the error:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : object 'vI' not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘party’
```

I've never seen an error like this when loading a package before, and I'm really at a loss.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try ´update.packages(checkBuilt=TRUE)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using a controlled computer at work, so installing/updating packages using a remote repository doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've just hit this one myself, shortly after changing systems.  I'm getting it when installing from a local package, but not when installing the same package from CRAN ...

Comment: as it turns out this was an obscure VirtualBox issue (went away when I moved my R library/package tree from a symbolic-linked directory to one within the native VirtualBox file system)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sys.getenv("vI_HOME")

if(Sys.getenv("vI_HOME")!="")    Sys.setenv(vI_HOME="")

library("party")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please **install party package separately**. So use:

```
install.packages("party", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Comment: While this might provide an answer to the question, some explanation is required. Please update the answer with some explanation of how and why this solution works.