# Error installing PARTY package in R

Tags: r, installation, party

Newbie R user here.
I wanted to install the party package in RStudio (Ver 0.98.507), but whether I install it directly from the CRAN repository or whether I save the file first and then load it in R, I get the following error message:

```
> install.packages("party")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Linda/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/party_1.0-15.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 731049 bytes (713 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 713 Kb

package ‘party’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Linda\AppData\Local\Temp\~~~~~~~\downloaded_packages
> library("party", lib.loc="C:/Users/Linda/Documents/R/win-library/3.1")
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  object 'vI' not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘party’
```

I am unable to interpret the error message. 
Every other package download and installation has worked so far though (caret, tree, rpart) so I am confused why this is not working.

Comment: Update everything of your system (`R`, *all* packages, external dependancies) and have a look at these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958161/object-not-found-error-when-loading-party-package-in-r & https://github.com/christophergandrud/Rep-Res-Book/issues/26

Answer (score 4):

Install "multcomp", then "party"

```
install.packages("multcomp")
library(multcomp)
install.packages("party")
library(party)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using ctree. and then I wanted to change the font size of the tree chart. I installed package "partykit". Then ctree doesn't work anymore. I was spending LONG time try to debug.. Later I found out there is also a ctree in the "partykit". In order to run ctree using "party" we would need to uninstall "partykit" so that there is no conflict..

(might not be exactly what the question is trying to solve. but hope this would be a reference to others :-))

Comment: This answer could be partially useful but should be improved a bit