# Install R package reshape in Linux with error object 'vI' not found

Tags: linux, r, installation

R version is 3.0.2
Didn't have issue when installing Rcpp, plyr etc. dependent packages

Error msg:

```
* installing *source* package \u2018reshape\u2019 ...
** package \u2018reshape\u2019 successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  object 'vI' not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package \u2018reshape\u2019
```

Comment: Have you tried installing from CRAN with `install.packages('reshape')`?

Comment: Yes but the connection was blocked. I can only download and then install :(

Comment: Are you on a virtual machine? ([related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23958161/489704))

Comment: Yea I can't change permission.

Comment: What OS (Linux builds are not all the same)?, versions (of R since compiling packages from source often requires the devel-install package if the headers need to be there) , ... of reshape)? And did you know that `reshape` has been superseded by `reshape2`? And why are you using fancy quotes? \u2018 seems a potential concern.

Comment: reshape2 gives the same error. It is red hat enterprise.