# Installing ggplot2 in R without being connected to the Internet

Tags: r, ggplot2, installation, r-package

I tried to install the package `ggplot2` on my computer with the command line:

```
install.packages("C:/r-packages/ggplot2",repos = NULL,type = "sourse")
```

Unfortunately I got the following error:

```
* installing *source* package 'ggplot2' ...
** package 'ggplot2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
object 'vI' not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'ggplot2'
* removing 'C:/Users/rachel/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/ggplot2'
 Warning in install.packages :
 running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.1/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
   "C:\Users\rachel\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" "C:/r-packages/ggplot2"' had      status 1
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘C:/r-packages/ggplot2’ had non-zero exit status
```

I don't have a connection to the internet so I can't download the package directly (This is why the `repos=NULL`). I also installed `Rtools`, but I still face the same problem. The same error appears when I am trying to install the packages `car` or `devtools`

```
 sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United    States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_0.12.6

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.3.1
```

Comment: Seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23958161/object-not-found-error-when-loading-party-package-in-r

Comment: Is `"source"` spelled wrong or is that an acceptable alternative?

Comment: I doubt seriously that "sourse" is an acceptable alternative. Probably just a typo error. However I also suspect that a real source package would have a name like `ggplot2_2.1.0.tar.gz` , and then there is the question if this user has the RTools package installed (maybe not needed) and any of the required packages in Imports: list of the DESCRIPTION file for that version: `digest, grid, gtable (>= 0.1.1), MASS, plyr (>= 1.7.1), reshape2, scales (>= 0.3.0), stats`. It's still almost certainly a duplicate of some other installation error.

Comment: Since you're on Windows, you're much better off to install from the zip file rather than compiling from source.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to unzip the source file that you [download from CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/index.html) (make sure it *is* the source, too: you want the one labelled ['Package source'](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/ggplot2_2.1.0.tar.gz)). So if you're installing from source and have downloaded to your typical Downloads folder, I'd expect it to look like this:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/rachel/Downloads/ggplot2_2.1.0.tar.gz")
```

(The `repos` argument is inferred if you're only installing one package at a time, and `type` defaults to `source`. You misspelt `source` in your example, but I don't think that's a problem because of the default.)

You could also download the Windows binary, which comes as a ZIP file, and install that in a similar way:

```
install.packages("C:/Users/rachel/Downloads/ggplot2_2.1.0.zip", type = 'win.binary')
```

Comment: I installed from sourse like this:

Comment: I installed fro a soure like you wrote, but it still have the same error